# Angular2 - What folder to store uploaded images?

Tags: angular, file-upload

What is the correct way to store uploaded image in an Angular2 Application ?

Should I put the file folder under:

```
\src\UPLOAD_DIR
```

or under:

```
\src\app\UPLOAD_DIR
```

?

Then, once I have defined the path, how can I reference the image in the html component ?

What should be the path ?

I'd like to reference images like this:

```
<img src="./UPLOAD_DIR/aaa.jpg />
```

So how do I have to move ?

Thanks

Comment: Question confused me! angular is client end and you will have some server side code to store image.  it all depend on server, how you store images. It might be in database or in folder. when images are uploaded, URL will be dynamic generated on server end to allow upload file with same name by different user.

Comment: What I have to do is uploading images under an Angular2 subfolder and use them in the application...
I need to know what if I have to store files under s\rc or under \src\app folder and how to use them in the html components files...

Comment: That you have to map folder with server side code you are using. Which technology you use on server side? On server side where you accept uploaded file from there you can save it in angular folder.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, I use IIS in this moment. My question is if there is a best practice for Angular2 on where to store image/files loaded by the users.
In this moment I'm using Assets folder, is it corect ?